# How to place two TextFields side by side

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I am trying to place two text fields side by side like the image shown below.

[image: Output I want to achieve]

This is the code I have so far for the single-line text fields.

```
       Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Contact No",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: You can check [ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put them inside a `Row` but you have to wrap each one of them with an `Expanded` widget like the following:

```
Row(
    children: [
        Expanded(child:,TextField()),
        SizedBox(width: 12), // Optional
        Expanded(child:,TextField()),
    ]
)
```

**NOTE:** The idea of wrapping `TextField` with an `Expanded` when using it inside a row is to allow Flutter to determine the correct render size of the field due to internal details in the Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Create a row and add 2 textfields like written below

```
Row(
  children: [
   TextField(),
   TextField(),
  ]
)
```